# See source of JavaScriptObject in GWT?

Tags: javascript, json, gwt

I have a JavaScriptObject that I'd like to see the code for so I can debug it. How can I do this?

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
// in a callback
public void onSuccess(JavaScriptObject result) {
    System.out.println("got - " + result.getData());
}

// prints: got - [1, 2, 3, {"foo": "bar}]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScriptObject has a .toString() method in the javadoc that says

> Makes a best-effort attempt to get a useful debugging string describing the given JavaScriptObject.

If that does not help you, perhaps you can use [JavaScript Overlay Types](http://code.google.com/intl/tr-TR/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html) to create a thin wrapper on your JavaScriptObject to define a method such as `getData()` to fulfill your requirements. You can directly access JSON fields that you know exists by using `this` in an overlay.